# control not found in custom template

Tags: asp.net

I take a user control file. I put this

```
<div  style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Header" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div style="width:65%;float:left;">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="LeftSide" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div style="width:35%;float:right;padding-top:20px;">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="RightSide" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Footer" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In code-behind

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Partial Public Class MainTemplate
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Private HeaderTemplateVar As ITemplate = Nothing
    Private LeftTemplateVar As ITemplate = Nothing
    Private RightTemplateVar As ITemplate = Nothing
    Private FooterTemplateVar As ITemplate = Nothing
    Private HeaderWidthVar As Integer

    <TemplateContainer(GetType(Container)), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
    Public Property HeaderTemplate() As ITemplate

        Get
            Return HeaderTemplateVar
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ITemplate)
            HeaderTemplateVar = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <TemplateContainer(GetType(Container)), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
   Public Property FooterTemplate() As ITemplate

        Get
            Return FooterTemplateVar
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ITemplate)
            FooterTemplateVar = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <TemplateContainer(GetType(Container)), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
   Public Property RightTemplate() As ITemplate

        Get
            Return RightTemplateVar
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ITemplate)
            RightTemplateVar = value
        End Set

    End Property

    <TemplateContainer(GetType(Container)), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
    Public Property LeftTemplate() As ITemplate

        Get
            Return LeftTemplateVar
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ITemplate)
            LeftTemplateVar = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

        If Not HeaderTemplate Is Nothing Then

            Dim HeaderContainer As New Container()
            HeaderTemplate.InstantiateIn(HeaderContainer)
            Header.Controls.Add(HeaderContainer)

        End If

        If Not LeftTemplate Is Nothing Then

            Dim LeftContainer As New Container()
            LeftTemplate.InstantiateIn(LeftContainer)
            LeftSide.Controls.Add(LeftContainer)

        End If

        If Not RightTemplate Is Nothing Then

            Dim RightContainer As New Container()
            RightTemplate.InstantiateIn(RightContainer)
            RightSide.Controls.Add(RightContainer)

        End If

        If Not FooterTemplate Is Nothing Then

            Dim FooterContainer As New Container()
            FooterTemplate.InstantiateIn(FooterContainer)
            Footer.Controls.Add(FooterContainer)

        End If

    End Sub


End Class
```

When I call this in UI, I put a button on the UI page that control is not appear in code-behind of UI.
I get this button event in code-behind.

```
<Yoma:Template ID="Test1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div  style="background-color:Silver;color:Red;width:100%;">Welcome</div>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <LeftTemplate>
                <p>he 1962 South Vietnamese Independence Palace bombing in Saigon was an aerial attack on 
                February 27, 1962, by two dissident Vietnam Air Force pilots, Second Lieutenant Nguyễn Văn 
                political association. Domestically, the incident was 
                reported to have increased plotting against Diem by his officers. (more...)</p>
        </LeftTemplate>
        <RightTemplate>
            <table align="right" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" style="width:300px; border: 1px Solid #78bafa;" bgcolor="#f3f7fa" id="AddUser">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <table style="width:260px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="30" colspan="2" valign="top">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td ><strong>Add Respondent</strong></td>
                                            <td align="right"></td> 
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="75"  >First Name:</td>
                                <td width="185"  ><input name="FirstName" type="text" runat="server" id="FirstName" size="8" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td  >Surname:</td>
                                <td  ><input name="Surname" type="text" id="Surname" size="12" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td  >Email:</td>
                                <td  ><input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" size="17" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" ><br />
                                    <asp:Button ID="AddRespondentButton" runat="server" Text="ADD RESPONDENT" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </RightTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <table style="width:900px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td >&copy; 2006-<%=Now.Date%> Easi-Answers Limited</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </Yoma:Template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of templated controls, template may get instantiated multiple times. Therefore, you will not find control references in generated code behind - because control gets created at runtime when template is instantiated. Such control references has to be found using `FindControl` method at template container (RightContainer in your case).

All you want is to attach event handler then you may use syntax such as

```
<asp:Button ID="AddRespondentButton" runat="server" Text="ADD RESPONDENT" OnClick="AddRespondentButton_Click" />
```

`AddRespondentButton_Click` will be an protected/public event handler method in the page code behind.

Comment: When I try this, I go the error that is Control 'Test1_ctl02_AddRespondentButton' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: @zanhtet, do your page (aspx) has form tag within it? If yes, it should have runat="server" and your template control instance must be within form tags.

Comment: @zanhtet, I am not sure about the reason. How about FindControl method - can you try Test1.FindControl("AddRespondentButton") gets you the ref to button?

Comment: while the button am inserting in the template, the error is appear

Comment: I want to get control event in code-behind. but i use find control. another way? If you know, tell me.

Comment: If FindControl is successful then you can attach the event programmatically - `AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf AddRespondentButton_Click`. I am not a VB.NET person, so verify the event attaching syntax.